# Lumen/Dingo API Dynamic Versioning

Tags: php, rest, routes, lumen, dingo-api

I'm using Lumen for my project, currently the way I version my API is through prefixing and using a specific corresponding controller like so:

```
$api->get('/v1/users', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\UserController@show');
$api->get('/v2/users', 'App\Api\V2\Controllers\UserController@show');
```

I want to change this, such that I take an argument from the user and use a controller based on that parameter.

```
This Route:
$api->get('/v{api_version}/users'...

Should use this controller: 
'App\Api\V{api_version}\Controllers\UserController@show'
```

I'm currently using Dingo along side Lumen, is there anyway to do this with either Lumen or Dingo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. But it's a little bit more complicated than in your example, but it's still a one-liner. Just define a closure and invoke your controller within it instead of passing the FQCN controller name directly.

**routes/web.php**

```
$app->get("api/v{version}/users", function ($version) use ($app) {
    return $app->make("App\Api\V{$version}\Controllers\UserController")->show();
});
```

---

If someone else is interested (as I was) how to achieve the same in an laravel installation: Just use the method `Controller::callAction()` after the controller was resolved

```
Route::get("api/v{version}/test", function ($version) {
    return app()->make('App\Api\V{$version}\Controllers\UserController')->callAction("show", [/* arguments */]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is really helpful, works the charm. I was wondering however, what exactly does make() do?